# gdb "Invalid binary operation on numbers"

Tags: gdb

At work, while debugging our program with gdb, it sometimes repsonds to 
a simple "next" command with "Invalid binary operation on numbers".
Mighty annoying.  Googling finds absolutely no hints.   It is C++, so 
perhaps that has something inside gdb confused in some way; I have no
clue.

Anyone?

(I can't get formatting to work right as a comment, so I'm adding to this area)

```
257       SingleBitBusMap::const_iterator sbb = fSingleBitBusMap.find(constituents.first.c_str());
(gdb) next
Invalid binary operation on numbers.
(gdb)
```

fSingleBitBusMap is a std::map
constituents is a std::pair
constituents.first is a std::string
and, after it says "Invalid binary operation on numbers", "bt" gives me this as the ENTIRE backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040fb40 in std::string::c_str ()
(gdb)
```

though, doing "tbreak +1" and "cont" and then "bt"
does once again get me a valid traceback.

Comment: can you share the piece of code on which you are running gdb and gdb session output where you observed the error.

Comment: Here's another backtrace after it reports "Invalid binary operation":
(gdb) 
Invalid binary operation on numbers.
(gdb) bt 6
#0  0x000000000040f2c0 in std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > ()
Invalid binary operation on numbers.
(gdb)

Comment: Here's a simple one:  Current line is a std::string = char buffer and after the "Invalid binary operatior", the bt shows us in std::string::operator=.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of that this could happen: you have some active `display` which requires GDB to evaluate some expression every time it stops, and that expression can't be evaluated, yielding `Invalid binary operation on numbers` error.

Use `info display` to see current "auto display" expressions.

Comment: I have no active displays.